# create table in a specific schema through c# in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a database and table in mySQL using C#. So far I can create a Schema in mysql through c#, but having trouble with creating table in that created schema.

User will enter the name of the schema to be created and then will enter the table name which will be created under the schema name entered before. Schema name and table names are taken in textbox values.

I am getting an error in table query the error is about syntax.

```
myQuery1.AppendFormat("CREATE SCHEMA {0}", databasenametxt.Text);
myQuery2.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE {0} (name VARCHAR(20)) WHERE 
database={0}",tblenametxt.Text,databasenametxt.Text);
string s1 = myQuery1.ToString();
string s2 = myQuery2.ToString();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(s1, coat);
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(s2, coat);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

myQuery1 is executed successfully and a schema is created with the name entered in databasenametxt.Text but in myquery2 I am getting error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: and what are the values you have sent it - no reserved words used? spaces

Comment: btw mysql docs dont suggest "where database = .." is valid syntax.

Comment: error is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE database=databasename' at line 1'"

Comment: @BugFinder I am sending the table and schema name where it should create the table.

Comment: I dont have mysql at work to check on however if the docs dont say "where database =" then chances are thats the error but you havent shown the error so everything is a guess so far

Comment: @BugFinder I have commented the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand it is that you want to dynamically create a schema and tables in it. I am not sure of the error you get, but try using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name ( column_name1 data_type, column_name2 data_type, column_name3 data_type, .... )
```

For replacing the `schema_name` and `table_name`, it should work like following:

```
myQuery2.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE {schema_name}.{table_name} ( {column_name1} {data_type}, .... ), your_schema_name, your_table_name, column_name1, data_type1);
```

You can also just add strings:

```
myQuery2.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE " + your_schema_name + "." + your_table_name + " ( " + column_name1 + " " + data_type1 + ")");
```

It is just that you are creating a query string, which would run on sql server.

Also, you can get all the msql syntax for creating a table at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: schema name and table_name are textbox values how should I write those values in your query?

Comment: Oh, I am not a C# expert but I believe there is nothing fancy in doing that. It should work the same way as you are replacing values now in your query. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comment the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE database=databasename' at line 1'"

is because "where database = .." is not valid syntax.

As schema is just a synonym for database in mysql you want

```
create database {0}
use {0}
create table {0} (`name` VARCHAR(20))
```

in each of your strings.  Why the change to name? its a reserved word.